# componentDidUpdate gets fired when I switch components in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

So I have two components in my storybook `RadioButton` and `RadioButtonWithIcons`. On initial render of both components, my `componentDidMount` fires to do some work. Then `ComponentDidUpdate` fires on any change in the component.

But if I switch from  `RadioButton` to `RadioButtonWithIcons` from the side panel, it fires of `RadioButtonWithIcons`'s `ComponentDidUpdate` right away... Why would this happen?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question but since the component is already Mounted, it only updates and doesnt unmount and then mounts again.

Comment: Ah I see. How can I get it to unmount when I change to a different story?

Comment: Can you show your code so I'll have a better look?

Comment: its a chunky component with a lot going on so im not sure if i can show the code. but the crux of the problem is that componentDidUpdate fires even when changing stories. i just need a way to run a fresh componentDidMount when that happens.

Comment: Can you show us your stories file?